# FirebaseRecyclerAdapter with action mode to delete items

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I'm trying to implement an Action Mode to delete items within FirebaseRecyclerView. The weird thing is that sometimes the deleted items are not the selected items. I'm think that error is in ToogleSelection method or RemoveItems method, but I'm don't know what it is.

**The Adapter Code:**

```
public class NewsAdapter extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Noticia, NoticiasViewHolder> {

    private int color;
    private int selectedColor;
    private NoticiasFragment fragment;
    private final Globals globals;
    private ActionMode actionMode;
    private final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    private SparseIntArray selectedItems = new SparseIntArray();

    public NewsAdapter(NoticiasFragment fragment, Query ref) {

        super(Noticia.class, R.layout.list_item_noticia, NoticiasViewHolder.class, ref);
        this.color = ContextCompat.getColor(fragment.getActivity(), R.color.background_card);
        this.selectedColor = ContextCompat.getColor(fragment.getActivity(), R.color.background_selected);
        this.globals = (Globals) fragment.getActivity().getApplicationContext();
        this.fragment = fragment;
    }


    @Override
    protected void populateViewHolder(NoticiasViewHolder viewHolder, final Noticia model, final int position) {

        viewHolder.imageView.setImageUrl(model.linkImg, globals.getImageLoader());
        viewHolder.bindToNoticia(fragment.getActivity(), model, dateFormat);

        final DatabaseReference noticiaRef = getRef(position);

        viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (getSelectedItemCount()>0) {

                    if (toggleSelection(position)) {
                        v.setBackgroundColor(selectedColor);

                    } else {
                        v.setBackgroundColor(color);
                        if (getSelectedItemCount()==0 && actionMode!=null) {
                            actionMode.finish();
                        }
                    }
                    return;
                }

                if (!Server.isOnline(fragment.getActivity(), R.string.sem_conexao_noticia))
                    return;

                Intent i = new Intent(fragment.getActivity(), NewsActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("Noticia", model);
                fragment.startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        viewHolder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

                if (toggleSelection(position)) {
                    v.setBackgroundColor(selectedColor);

                    if (actionMode != null)
                        return true;
                    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) fragment.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
                    actionMode = toolbar.startActionMode(mActionModeCallback);
                    actionMode.setTitle("1 selecionado");

                } else {
                    v.setBackgroundColor(color);
                    if (getSelectedItemCount() == 0 && actionMode != null) {
                        actionMode.finish();
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

        if (selectedItems.get(position)!=0)
            viewHolder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(selectedColor);
        else viewHolder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(color);

    }


    /* Returns selected items count */
    public int getSelectedItemCount() {
        return selectedItems.size();
    }

    /* Select/unselect for deletion */
    public boolean toggleSelection(int position) {
        boolean b;
        if (selectedItems.get(position)!=0) {
            selectedItems.delete(position);
            b = false;
        }
        else {
            selectedItems.put(position, position); 
            b = true;
        }
        int n = getSelectedItemCount();
        if (n>0 && actionMode!=null) {
            actionMode.setTitle(String.valueOf(n) + (n==1 ? " selecionado" : " selecionados"));
        }
        return b;
    }

    /* Action to delete selected items */
    private void removeItems() {

        String userId = fragment.getUid();

        while (selectedItems.size()>0) {

            int position = selectedItems.keyAt(0);
            DatabaseReference noticiaRef = getRef(position);
            fragment.mDatabase.child("user-news").child(userId).child(noticiaRef.getKey()).removeValue();
            selectedItems.removeAt(0);
        }
    }

    private ActionMode.Callback mActionModeCallback = new ActionMode.Callback() {

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {

            MenuInflater inflater = actionMode.getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_delete_noticias, menu);

            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) fragment.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            toolbar.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(fragment.getActivity(), R.color.accent2));

            TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) fragment.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
            tabLayout.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(fragment.getActivity(), R.color.accent2));

            final Globals globals = (Globals) fragment.getActivity().getApplicationContext();
            globals.isInActionMode = true;

            ((MainActivity) fragment.getActivity()).updatePage(0);

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                Window window = (fragment.getActivity()).getWindow();
                window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
                window.setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(fragment.getActivity(), R.color.accent3));
            }

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(final ActionMode actionMode, MenuItem menuItem) {

            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {

                case R.id.menu_main_delete_noticias:

                    new SweetAlertDialog(fragment.getContext(), SweetAlertDialog.WARNING_TYPE)
                            .setTitleText(fragment.getResources().getString(R.string.excluir_noticias))
                            .setContentText(fragment.getResources().getString(R.string.excluir_noticias_message))
                            .setCancelText(fragment.getResources().getString(R.string.btn_nao_excluir))
                            .setConfirmText(fragment.getResources().getString(R.string.btn_sim_excluir))
                            .showCancelButton(true)
                            .setCancelClickListener(new SweetAlertDialog.OnSweetClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(SweetAlertDialog sDialog) {
                                    actionMode.finish();
                                    sDialog.cancel();
                                }
                            })
                            .setConfirmClickListener(new SweetAlertDialog.OnSweetClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(SweetAlertDialog sDialog) {

                                    /* Execute deletion */
                                    removeItems();

                                    actionMode.finish();
                                    sDialog
                                            .setTitleText(fragment.getResources().getString(R.string.noticias_excluidas))
                                            .setContentText(fragment.getResources().getString(R.string.noticias_excluidas_message))
                                            .setConfirmText(fragment.getResources().getString(R.string.btn_ok))
                                            .showCancelButton(false)
                                            .setConfirmClickListener(null)
                                            .changeAlertType(SweetAlertDialog.SUCCESS_TYPE);
                                }
                            })
                            .show();
                    return true;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode aMode) {

            fragment.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.action_mode_bar).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) fragment.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            toolbar.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(fragment.getActivity(), R.color.primary));

            TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) fragment.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
            tabLayout.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(fragment.getActivity(), R.color.primary));

            final Globals globals = (Globals) fragment.getActivity().getApplicationContext();
            globals.isInActionMode = false;

            ((MainActivity) fragment.getActivity()).selectPage(3);

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                Window window = fragment.getActivity().getWindow();
                window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
                window.setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(fragment.getActivity(), R.color.primaryDark));
            }
            selectedItems.clear();
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            actionMode = null;
        }
    };
}
```

**EDIT:**

Seems to me that the index positions from FirebaseRecyclerView are not updated immediatly after the remotions.
I realized that, if I have 20 items and delete the first 15 items, and if I try to delete the new first one, I get the following error:

```
08-01 21:12:35.816 10747-10747/com.doeal.doeal E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                             Process: com.doeal.doeal, PID: 10747
                                                             java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 15, size is 5
                                                                 at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
                                                                 at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
                                                                 at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseArray.getItem(FirebaseArray.java:52)
                                                                 at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.getRef(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:150)
                                                                 at com.doeal.doeal.adapters.NoticiasAdapter.removeItems(NoticiasAdapter.java:187)
                                                                 at com.doeal.doeal.adapters.NoticiasAdapter.access$700(NoticiasAdapter.java:43)
                                                                 at com.doeal.doeal.adapters.NoticiasAdapter$4$1.onClick(NoticiasAdapter.java:248)
                                                                 at cn.pedant.SweetAlert.SweetAlertDialog.onClick(SweetAlertDialog.java:372)
                                                                 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5201)
                                                                 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21163)
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

I tried execute NotifyDatasetChanged to rebuild the indexes, but has no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, that's my mistake. In the PopulateViewHolder method, I was passing the int position instead the reference key to the OnClickListener and OnLongClickListener events. The more relevant changes are:

```
private Map<String, String> selectedItems = new HashMap<>();
```

...

```
viewHolder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            if (toggleSelection(noticiaRef.getKey())) {
                v.setBackgroundColor(selectedColor);

                if (actionMode != null)
                    return true;
                Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) fragment.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
                actionMode = toolbar.startActionMode(mActionModeCallback);
                actionMode.setTitle("1 selecionado");
            } else {
                v.setBackgroundColor(color);
                if (getSelectedItemCount() == 0 && actionMode != null) {
                    actionMode.finish();
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

...

```
public boolean toggleSelection(String key) {
    boolean b;
    if (selectedItems.get(key)!=null) {
        selectedItems.remove(key);
        b = false;
    }
    else {
        selectedItems.put(key, key);
        b = true;
    }
    int n = getSelectedItemCount();
    if (n>0 && actionMode!=null) {
        actionMode.setTitle(String.valueOf(n) + (n==1 ? " selecionado" : " selecionados"));
    }
    return b;
}

private void removeItems() {
    String userId = fragment.getUid();

    Iterator iterator = selectedItems.keySet().iterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext()) {
        String key=(String) iterator.next();
        fragment.mDatabase.child("user-news").child(userId).child(key).removeValue();
    }
    selectedItems.clear();
}
```